# track history of active record changes and its association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, history

I want to track the history the active record and association. I have a `many to many`
association:

```
class BookList
  has_many :book_list_items
  has_many :books, through: :book_list_items
end

class BookListItem
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :book_list

  attr_accessable :position
end

class Book
  has_many :book_list_items
  has_many :book_lists, through: :book_list_items
end
```

how do I track the history of `BookList` like this:

- add book to a book list
- remove book from a book list
- update position of a book in a book list

how do I implement this structure

Comment: I'm not sure `acts_as_version` or `vestal_versions` can do this.

Comment: You'd need to provide more info about what information you'd expect to get from this history. In the meantime, see if [papertrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) meets your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail

This is a great rails cast that will work great for you based on the information you provided

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [active_snapshot](https://github.com/westonganger/active_snapshot). It is a much simpler and easy to use gem for model and its associations tracking for ruby and rails applications

I understand the question is too old for this answer, but this might help someone else